# Rspec test failure: Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us' Hartl Ch. 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, and I am doing the Chapter 3 exercises. Can someone please explain why this test is failing?

I am getting the failure

```
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:39 # 
Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
```

Controller

```
  class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def Contact
  end
end
```

About.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>About Us</h1>
```

Spec.rb

```
describe "About page" do

  it "should have the h1 'About Us'" do
    visit '/static_pages/about'
  page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'About Us')
end
it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
  visit '/static_pages/about'
  page.should have_selector('title',
                :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
  end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"

  get "static_pages/help"

  get "static_pages/about"

  get "static_pages/Contact"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
page.should have_xpath("//title", :text => "About Us")
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Can you help me understand how it works?

Comment: I think if you are using have_selector, try replace text with content like: `page.should have_selector('h1', :content => 'About Us')`. Actually I recommend to use [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to test your view. have_selector from Rspec is learned from this. It's more easy to use for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following MHartl's tutorial and you're using the gem 'Capybara', I can confirm that changing your ':text => ...' to ':content => ...' will make your tests pass. Thanks to [@Kuo Jimmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051942/kuo-jimmy).